# Fourier transform of Hamiltonian of free particles in electromagnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, solid-state-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, fourier-transform

It is well known that the Hamiltonian of free particles in an electromagnetic field in real space is:
$$
H_R=\frac{1}{2m}\int d\mathbf{r} \Psi^\dagger (\mathbf{r}) \left(-i\hbar\nabla-e\mathbf{A(r)}\right)^2\Psi (\mathbf{r})
$$
In Fourier space, it is given as
$$
H_F=\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}  \left(\mathbf{p}-e\mathbf{A}\right)^2c^\dagger_\mathbf{k}c_\mathbf{k}
$$
In almost all the literature (that I have read), the dependence of $\mathbf{A}$ is not mentioned. Is it $\mathbf{A}\equiv\mathbf{A(r)}$ or $\mathbf{A}\equiv\mathbf{A(k)}$?

I believe it is $\mathbf{A}\equiv\mathbf{A(r)}$ because otherwise, we can't get the expression for $H_F$. Why don't we Fourier transform $\mathbf{A(r)}$? And is not $H_F\equiv H_F(\mathbf{r})$?

Comment: What reference are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming you are using 2nd quantization. To make things simple, I’ll take $\hbar=1$, take the case of fields defined on $\mathbb R$, even though you were referring to a compact domain to get a discrete sum in Fourier space. The Fourier transform of $f$ (complex function or operator function) will be defined by the convention:
$$
\tilde f(k)=\int dx f(x)e^{-ikx} \\
f(x)=\int \frac{dk}{2\pi}\tilde f(k)e^{ikx} \\
$$
This gives Parceval’s identity:
$$
\int dx f(x)^*g(x)=\int \frac{dk}{2\pi} \tilde f(k)^*\tilde g(k)
$$

In general, when you have many factors, you can formally substitute the Fourier transform, invert the integrals and use the identity:
$$
\int dx e^{ikx}=2\pi\delta(x)
$$
to cancel an integral. Another more involved example is:
$$
\int dx f_1(x)^*g_1(x) f_2(x)^*g_2(x) =\int_{k_1+k_2=l_1+l_2}\frac{dk_1}{2\pi} \frac{dl_1}{2\pi} \frac{dk_2}{2\pi} \frac{dl_2}{2\pi} \tilde f_1(k_1)^*\tilde g_1(l_1) \tilde f_2(k_2)^*\tilde g_2(l_2)
$$

You can apply this method to your Hamiltonian. Using integration by parts and discarding boundary terms, it’s best to rewrite it as:
$$
H=\int dx \frac{1}{2m} [(-i\nabla -eA)\Psi]^\dagger (-i\nabla -eA)\Psi
$$
Applying the previous results, you get (my comment was wrong):
$$
H= \int_{k_1+k_2=l_1+l_2}\frac{dk_1}{2\pi} \frac{dl_1}{2\pi} \frac{dk_2}{2\pi} \frac{dl_2}{2\pi} \frac{1}{2m} (k_1 \delta(k_2)-e\tilde A(k_2)^*)(l_1 \delta(l_2)-e\tilde A(l_2)) \tilde \Psi(k_1)^\dagger \tilde\Psi(l_1)
$$

Hope this helps